# how to develop a tool for phonological transformation purpose?

Tags: nlp

I want to develop a tool which will accept phonological transformation rules and input word list and subsequently it will produce output word list.For this how the algorithm will look like?

Comment: To save you some time.. a lot of these already exist: http://www.zompist.com/sca2.html http://zounds.artefact.org.nz/

Comment: Anyway, it might be sufficient to run chains of regular expressions on the input phones.

Comment: yeah,they are good...actually, I am interested how those tools are working; I mean the algorithm they use...@JonGauthier

Comment: take a look at this: https://github.com/dmort27/HsSPE

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin : I have visited the link you provided,but they have not provided instructions on how to install/run the software.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these functions: https://github.com/nrc-cnrc/InuktitutToolkit/tree/master/Inuktitut-Java/phonology/research

Comment: I could not understand some functions as the developer has not elaborated those briefly as comment. Also in many places English language is not followed while giving comment; so I could not understand some functions in the link you provided @Daniel